# Problema al imprimir las claves de un diccionario

Tags: python-2.7

Estoy con un ejercicio muy simple de diccionarios en python, pero estos se me atragantan, es el ejercicio de una serie de estudiantes (Lloyd,Alice,Tyler. Lo pongo porque lo he visto por aquí) y ya en lo de hacer la ficha para que queden el nombre y las calificaciones cada uno en una fila me estoy liando, sé que lo puedo hacer manualmente con un bucle for e insertando cada alumno y calificación, pero doy por hecho que se puede hacer de una forma más rápida y menos tediosa. Yo tengo hecho esto:

```
     lloyd={
     'name':'Lloyd',
     'homework':[90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
     'quizzes':[88.0,40.0,94.0],
     'tests':[75.0,90.0]
     }
     alice={
     'name':'Alice',
     'homework':[100.0,92.0,98.0,100.0],
     'quizzes':[82.0,83.0,91.0],
     'tests':[89.0,97.0]
     }
     tyler={
     'name':'Tyler',
     'homework':[0.0,87.0,75.0,22.0],
     'quizzes':[0.0,75.0,78.0],
     'tests':[100.0,100.0] 
     }

     lista_estudiantes=['lloyd','alice','tyler']

     def ficha():
         for i in lista_estudiantes:
             print ''
         print i
         print 'Homework:',i['homework']
         print 'tests:',i['tests']
         print 'quizzes:',i['quizzes']
         return
     ficha()
```

Y el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
     File "D:/Users/sacu/.spyder/refresco1.py", line 77, in ficha
     print 'Homework:',i['homework']

     TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Ruego me echen un cable, soy un poco torpe.

Answer (score 2):

El valor de `i` es un string porque estas sacándolo de una lista de strings. Quita las comillas de los elementos de la lista de estudiantes para que sean los nombres de los estudiantes:

```
lloyd =
{
    'name':'Lloyd',
    'homework':[90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
    'quizzes':[88.0,40.0,94.0],
    'tests':[75.0,90.0]
}

alice =
{
    'name':'Alice',
    'homework':[100.0,92.0,98.0,100.0],
    'quizzes':[82.0,83.0,91.0],
    'tests':[89.0,97.0]
}

tyler =
{
    'name':'Tyler',
    'homework':[0.0,87.0,75.0,22.0],
    'quizzes':[0.0,75.0,78.0],
    'tests':[100.0,100.0]
}

lista_estudiantes = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

def ficha():
    for i in lista_estudiantes:
        print ''
        print i['name']
        print 'Homework:',i['homework']
        print 'tests:',i['tests']
        print 'quizzes:',i['quizzes']
    return
 ficha()
```

Acomodé el código a mi estilo, no es tan difícil de notar xD.